# XmlSerializer: keep newline (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, xmlserializer

> Code and version: .NET Framework 3.5 // vb.net

How I can keep the line break of a string field? The line break is saved in the database with Environment.NewLine

**Original string with newline**

> this is line 1
>
> this is line 2
>
> this is line 3

I am tried the next codes, but no success:

```
Dim ws As New XmlWriterSettings()
ws.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize
Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Facturae))
Using wr As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(_ficheroXML, ws)
  ser.Serialize(wr, fac)
End Using
```

or

```
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Facturae))
Dim xtw As XmlTextWriter = New XmlTextWriter(New StreamWriter(_ficheroXML, False))
serializer.Serialize(xtw, fac)
xtw.Flush()
xtw.Close()
```

**xml output**:

```
<ItemDescription>this is line 1 this is line 2 this is line 3</ItemDescription>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep XmlSerializer from killing NewLines in Strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340180/how-to-keep-xmlserializer-from-killing-newlines-in-strings)

Comment: I had already seen this article and tested. But no success, returns the code that i put in my question

Comment: How do you observe that `<ItemDescription>`? If you do nothing and do not touch or provide xml writer settings, the new lines are preserved.

Comment: If you already used that solution, always mention that in your question, then surely you only have an imaginary problem.  Caused by looking at the .xml file with a text viewer that cannot properly handle the line endings.  Like Notepad.